# Access Denied for Read-Only Group

Tags: permissions

I am running a team site in SharePoint 2010 that is being used for various things.  Some of the content on this site is intended for various users to be able to read without the ability to edit.  I have added a test user to the Site Visitors group with read permission, however, when I tried to access the site with this account, I receive an error that access is denied.  I am not entirely sure why this is being blocked.  The document libraries, master page library, and site pages library all show the ability to allow read access.  If I add this particular user to the Site Members group with Contribute permissions, they are able to access the site just fine.

I have not edited the permission lists in anyway (they are all still running with the default permissions) though I have stopped inheriting permissions from the parent site and am using a customer master page for this particular team site.  I also verified that this user account is not in the deny all user policy from central administration.

I am at a loss as to what to what I should check or what I am missing from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I had modified the master page for the site when it was first created, then never published it to the site.  Once the page was published, I was able to access the site with read-only permissions.